# What kind of artifacts do pip repos use?

Tags: pypi, python-packaging

I understand the difference between a python module and package, but I cannot find a clear answer that tells me what type of artifact the pip repos truly manage in the end.

For example, if I write a big python application like QT, what artifact do I need to build inorder to upload it to a pip repository server? Is it just a zip of the folder, the raw folder (unlikely and I hope not) or a special run-able python compressed format analogous to how java uses WAR files.

Comment: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging.html

Comment: In short it is "wheels" that you should build and upload to PyPI. More here: https://packaging.python.org/

Comment: okay, so the answer would the following: "pip will accept the following artifacts: a pure python script, a limited set of standard compressed binary format such as ZIP and a proprietary compressed format called WHL for wheel". Sound good?

Comment: About what _pip_ can install: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install